# Web Api Route issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am using Web API and am trying to call a PUT method for updating a user.  I have changed my routing to allow for specific methods to be called, like so;  (this is working for other methods).

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
             "WithActionApi",
             "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
         );

        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultApi",
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { action = "DefaultAction", id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But I am getting a 404 error when I try to PUT a user to the following url like this;

```
// The url is:  http://mysite/  
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Account/UserInfo/" + user.UserId, user);
```

The url looks like the following.  I have also tried "api/Account/".

```
http://mysite/api/account/userinfo/{guid}
```

The method looks like this in my controller.  The method signature was already scaffolded from the default controller class for another controller - I have only added the attributes and moved it to the Account controller.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    ...
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("UserInfo/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult PutUserInfo(Guid id, User userdetails)
    { }
```

I also have Can anyone see something I am doing incorrectly here?  I am quite stuck with this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding the following route attribute above my putuserinfo(guid, user) method instead.

```
[Route("{userid:Guid}")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added the following :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2